# Use jQuery imgAreaSelect on a resized image

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm using [imgareaselect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) to get the coordinates of a selection. However, due to the "max-width: 100%;" line in my CSS, the coordinates are wrong for the original image size.

Now I have a solution with a scrollable parent div which is not really cool. I tried to make some algorithm to calculate the new coordinates but I see again, I am very bad at maths.

Any ideas how to do this? Or you maybe know a better plugin (I am not looking for cropping images, I just want select something)

Comment: I gave up with imgAreaSelect. My advice: Use jCrop, as it provides functionality for selecting areas too (without cropping)

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem and did this to solve it:

```
var image = document.getElementById('yourImgId');

// Take the original size from image with naturalHeight - Width
var originalHeight = image.naturalHeight;
var originalWidth = image.naturalWidth;

// Show the original size in console to make sure is correct (optional):
console.log('IMG width: ' + originalWidth + ', height: ' + originalHeight);

// Enable imgAreaSelect on your image
$('yourImg#yourImgId').imgAreaSelect({
    aspectRatio: '1:1',
    handles: true,
    fadeSpeed: 200,
    imageHeight: originalHeight, 
    imageWidth: originalWidth,
    onSelectChange: getCoordinates // this function below
    });
```

Then deal with the original size:

```
function getCoordinates(img, selection) {

    if (!selection.width || !selection.height){
    return;
        }

    // With this two lines i take the proportion between the original size and
    // the resized img
    var porcX = img.naturalWidth / img.width;
    var porcY = img.naturalHeight / img.height;

    // Send the corrected coordinates to some inputs:
    // Math.round to get integer number
    // (selection.x1 * porcX) to correct the coordinate to real size
    $('input#x1').val(Math.round(selection.x1 * porcX));
    $('input#y1').val(Math.round(selection.y1 * porcY));
    $('input#x2').val(Math.round(selection.x2 * porcX));
    $('input#y2').val(Math.round(selection.y2 * porcY));
    $('input#w').val(Math.round(selection.width * porcX));
    $('input#h').val(Math.round(selection.height * porcY));
    }
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: hey @kidkamek I know it's been a few years but I just wanna say good work! this is great stuff.. getting the real height of selection, exactly what I was looking for. thank you.

Comment: @kidkamek. This is some really cool code. Thanks for your help. This really saved me. I have been searching for the fix for 3 days. I was about to switch to cropperjs but somehow I landed to your answer and it really saved my day. Thanks a lot.